# Do not redirect but show error on confirm_delete template if error occurs during DeleteView delete call

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am currently trying to override the `DeleteView`'s inherited `delete` method to implement my desired behavior. However, I'm relatively new to the Django framework and Python in general and don't know what to do.
The goal is to delete an object and if a `ProtectedError` occurs, the `confirm_delete` template should display an error message describing the issue and the user should not be redirected to `success_url`. My first approach, similar to other forms, was to pack the error into `form.non_field_error`, but I don't know how to access it.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    try:
        self.object.delete()
        # Redirect to success_url
    except ProtectedError:
        pass
        # Add error to confirm_delete template / delete Form and stay on the delete confirmation page (don't delete)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

**So how is it possible that the user is only redirected to success_url after a successful delete, but an error message appears on the confirm_delete template in case of a ProtectedError and no redirection takes place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically do the same thing the `get()` method of the class would do and just add some information about the error to the context.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    try:
        self.object.delete()
        # Redirect to success_url
    except ProtectedError:
        context = self.get_context_data(
            object=self.object,
            error='Object is protected'
        )
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Check out https://ccbv.co.uk to get a better idea how Django Class based views work under the hood.

You then have to display the error in your template. Here is an example with the template from the Django docs:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if error }}<p class="error">{{ error }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```